# .NET Prism Bootstrapper GetModuleCatalog question

Tags: .net, prism, bootstrapper

Can someone please explain where `GetModuleCatalog (Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.GetModuleCatalog())` is called in the Prism shell? I understand that it needs to be overridden in the application Bootstrapper, but I could not find out where it is called internally when running the Bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ModuleManager calls it when Run() is called from your Bootstrapper.  If you look at the [implementation of the UnityBootstrapper](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/26112#496110), you'll see this line of code in the Run() method:

```
this.InitializeModules();
```

This method, in turn, does this:

```
IModuleManager manager;   
manager = this.Container.Resolve<IModuleManager>();        
manager.Run();
```

So, looking now at the default implementation of IModuleManager (just ModuleManager) you see the modules initialize.  If you'd like to peruse the ModuleManager code, you can see it on codeplex here:
[ModuleManager.cs](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/26112#495473)

Comment: Sure thing.  It's good you are diving into the CAL code.  It'll definitely help you along the way.  I hate feeling like something is magic.